# I am getting issue in broadcasting and listening event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

First.js

```
scope.menuItemClick = function (def, callbackText, keepMenuOpen) {

  console.log(def);

  if(def.automationId === "Print"){

  console.log("before broadcast");

  $scope.$root.$broadcast("printingForms","my Data");

  console.log("after broadcast");

}
```

Second.js

```
$scope.$on("printingForms",(event, data) => {

  console.log(data);

  console.log("listening");

});
```

I am not able to listen the broadcast event though I am broadcasting it from root. can anyone help me?
Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$rootScope` to broadcast events. Just inject `$rootScope` on your controller as same as `$scope`

**Controller 1**

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("printingForms","my Data");
```

**Controller 2**

```
$rootScope.$on("printingForms",function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Yahh its work always with $rootScope. So is it compulsory that if I am broadcasting with $rootScope.$broadcast(some stuff) then I have to listen with the same $rootScope.$on(some stuff) ? Am I allow to listen with $scope.$on(some stuff) ?????

Comment: `$rootScope` is the parent of all controllers and therefore it can see all the children. If  you communicate between to controllers this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Worth to check relationship of your 2 controllers. Who is a parent and who is child. If both controllers run in parallel, check who loads 1st.

The main reason it might not work is your second controller loaded after you called `$scope.$root.$broadcast("printingForms","my Data");`

Also, even `$scope.$root` holds a reference to the `$rootScope` will be better to use `$rootScope`

Comment: how to check who loads 1st? I have same doubt also. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DEVANGPATEL in controller 1st line print `console.log()` and be sure that  `Ctrl2` is loaded before you call `console.log("before broadcast");`

Comment: yes you are right..ctrl2 is not loading before...if such thing happens than what should I have to do other than $rootScope?

Comment: @DEVANGPATEL you can change your  logic to call `$broadcast` after Ctrl2 is loaded. You can use `$rootScope` but it can lead to unexpected behavior is some cases, for example you get `$on` callback twice .etc .